# Converted UWP... Nothing Happens

Tags: desktop-bridge

I have converted a Win32 Application to UWP using MakeAppX and it doesn't seem to run. When I click the icon in the start menu literally nothing happens except a busy icon briefly appears on the cursor.

I completed the same process with Notepad++ and all it's DLLs and that worked fine (using the exact same manifest file, just changing the exe)

My questions are:

1. Where does the UWP save files that it creates/temporary files etc? If I run an executable and it generates files next to it, where would that be when you run a UWP?
2. Can I set that location in the AppxManifest?
3. Is there anyway to see if it has run correctly or not?

Edit:

Could this be a file permissions issue? My application needs to write to 'C:\MyFolder' & creates a folder with a load of files next to the executable upon startup and that doesn't happen.

So looking into this a bit more I came across [this blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare) which discusses preparing for conversion. I think the above file accesses probably contravene the following:

- **Your app writes to the install directory for your app.** For example, your app writes to a log file that you put in the same directory as your exe. This isn't supported, so you'll need to find another location, like the local app data store.

This looks like a fairly halting issue, am I correct in that assumption?

Answer (score 1):

If your app is writing to the install directory you will need to change that code to write to your local app data folder instead, as the preparation guide calls out.

Write operations to the install directory are not allowed in order to ensure the ability for the app deployment stack to perform seamless, differential updates and clean uninstalls of your app.

Btw, to debug through your app launch failures you can do the following in Visual Studio: Debug -> Other Debug Target -> Debug Installed App Package -> select your app from the list of installed apps.

Comment: Thanks, I think I need to debug the startup process to see where it stops